# Warn me when the equation number is pushed to the next line

Tags: equations, amsmath

Is it possible to let `amsmath` warn me when the equation is too long and pushes the number to the next line?

I expect either it prints  `Equation (1) too long` to console or it makes the `(1)` part red.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        A+B+C+D+R+F+G+H+I+J+L+M+N+O+P
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't want to say it is impossible but it's definitely a hard problem, because `amsmath` relies on the `\eqno` primitive to do this work for the `equation` environment.

```
\hsize=8cm
$$A+B+C+D+R+F+G+H+I+J+L+M+N+O+P\eqno(1)$$
\bye
```

[image]

So the only way I see is to override the `\eqno` primitive and measure the penalties to see whether the number will be flushed to the next line.

---

For the `align` family of environments it is a little easier because tag shifting is handled by macros, which you simply hook your custom error or warning into

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\place@tag{%
    \iftagsleft@
        \kern-\tagshift@
        \if1\shift@tag\row@\relax
            \errmessage{Equation too wide}%
            \rlap{\vbox{%
                \normalbaselines
                \boxz@
                \vbox to\lineht@{}%
                \raise@tag
            }}%
        \else
            \rlap{\boxz@}%
        \fi
        \kern\displaywidth@
    \else
        \kern-\tagshift@
        \if1\shift@tag\row@\relax
            \errmessage{Equation too wide}%
            \llap{\vtop{%
                \raise@tag
                \normalbaselines
                \setbox\@ne\null
                \dp\@ne\lineht@
                \box\@ne
                \boxz@
            }}%
        \else
            \llap{\boxz@}%
        \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        A+B+C+D+R+F+G+H+I+J+L+M+N+O+P
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

---

Another possibility would be to typeset the equation twice, but once with zero width (using `\vphantom`), such that the number can't go on the second line.  Then compare the height of the regular typeset equation with the zero-width one.  If the height of the regular one is larger than the other one, there was a line break.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{warnequation}{
  \setbox0=\vbox{\begin{equation}\BODY\end{equation}}%
  \setbox1=\vbox{\begin{equation}\vphantom{\BODY}\end{equation}}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\ht1
    \errmessage{Equation too wide}%
  \fi
  \box0
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{warnequation}
        A+B+C+D+R+F+G+H+I+J+L+M+N+O+P
    \end{warnequation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we **assume** `align` gives the same result as `equation` does and throw things into `align` and test it? Or, test the height of `\vbox` with and without `\eqno`?

Comment: @Symbol1 No, you can't assume that `align` and `equation` gives the same thing because `align` always typesets the formula at natural width (using `$` inside a `\halign`), whereas `equation` can apply horizontal stretch and shrink because it uses the `$$` primitive.

Comment: Does that mean `align` is more *harsh* than `$$`? I am OK with false alarm.

Comment: @Symbol1 I have added another proposal.